# ALSA unexpected results when called from shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, alsa

The ALSA lib contains two API versions, enabled by defining ALSA_PCM_OLD_HW_PARAMS_API for accessing the older one. It employs some advanced trickery (using the `.symver` assembly directive) to enable a single C library to contain different functions, with the same name but different arguments (for the old and new API). This is all and well, but causes trouble in certain circumstances.

As an example, let's create two source files. The first is main.cpp:

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

void lib_func();

void local_func()
{
    int err;
    unsigned int rate = 22050;
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
    assert(snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", snd_pcm_stream_t(0), 0) >= 0);
    assert(snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params) >= 0);
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &rate, 0);
    printf("err out of lib: %d\n", err);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    local_func();
    lib_func();
}
```

The second one is mylib.cpp:

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

void lib_func()
{
    int err;
    unsigned int rate = 22050;
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
    assert(snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", snd_pcm_stream_t(0), 0) >= 0);
    assert(snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params) >= 0);
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &rate, 0);
    printf("err in lib: %d\n", err);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
}
```

Note that the contents of `local_func()` and `lib_func()` are identical except for the printed message.

On a Linux box (we tested Ubuntu 12/gcc 4.6.3 and Ubuntu 14/gcc 4.8.4) build and run with:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o libmylib.so mylib.cpp && g++ main.cpp -lasound -L . -lmylib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
```

The result we get when running is:

```
err out of lib: 0
err in lib: 192000
```

This means that `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near` is behaving differently between the two code modules. In the shared library it is mistakenly calling the old version of the function, which expects an `unsigned int val` for the sample rate as opposed to the new which expects `unsigned int *val`, and returns a sample rate (192000, since it didn't accept our input) instead of an error code.

We've found a workaround for this problem: add the `-lasound` argument to the linker when creating the shared library. However, this is still a bug, where some users (such as this one, whom we believe had this exact problem: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near-returns-huge-value-900199/ ) can run into cases where a program compiles and links with no errors or warnings and yet incorrect behavior occurs.

Can someone explain what is going on here, and perhaps this problem could be acknowledged as a bug and fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. If you don't add `-lasound` when linking `libmylib.so`, the linker cannot see symbol versions, so it adds non-versioned references to undefined symbols. When the runtime linker binds non-versioned symbols, it tries to use the earliest version.

---

ALSA has the following definitions for `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near`:

```
$ readelf -Ws /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 | grep set_rate_near
   255: 0000000000062640    72 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near@ALSA_0.9
   256: 000000000005d140    61 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near@@ALSA_0.9.0rc4
  1115: 000000000005d140    61 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near@@ALSA_0.9
```

There is an older `ALSA_0.9` version, and a newer `ALSA_0.9.0rc4`, the latter marked as default (`@@`), which will be used when the static linker (`ld`) links against `-lasound`.

When `ld` links `libmylib.so` without `-lasound`, `libmylib.so` ends up having an undefined and *non-versioned* reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near`:

```
$ readelf -Ws libmylib.so | grep set_rate_near
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near
    31: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near
```

While `a.out`, which has been linked against `-lasound`, contains a reference against the default version:

```
$ readelf -Ws a.out | grep set_rate_near
    15: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near@ALSA_0.9.0rc4 (5)
    56: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near@@ALSA_0.9.0rc4
```

Then, when the runtime linker (`ld.so`) uses this information, it ends up binding different versions of `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near` for `libmylib.so` and `a.out`:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=bindings LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out 2>&1 | grep set_rate_near
     11364:     binding file ./libmylib.so [0] to /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near'
     11364:     binding file /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 [0] to /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `__snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near' [ALSA_0.9]
     11364:     binding file ./a.out [0] to /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near' [ALSA_0.9.0rc4]
```

---

This behavior is documented. From Ulrich Drepper's [DSO howto](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) §3.8:

> All methods which depend on symbol versioning have one requirement in
>   common: it is absolutely necessary for the users of the DSO to always
>   link with it.
>
> [...]
>
> The problem is that unless the DSO containing the definitions is used
>   at link time, the linker cannot add a version name to the undefined
>   reference. Following the rules for symbol versioning [[4](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/symbol-versioning)] this means
>   the earliest version available at runtime is used which usually is not
>   the intended version.

The referenced [document](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/symbol-versioning), in *"Symbol lookup"*, then goes on to explain that when trying to bind a non-versioned reference to a versioned definition, it tries the following:

- It tries the `BASE` version, at index 1 in the table of version definitions in the ELF file.
- It tries the baseline version at index 2, i.e. the first version used when the file started used symbol versions.
- Otherwise, if the symbol is only defined for a version, that version of the symbol is used.

The table of version definitions looks like this:

```
$ readelf -a /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 | awk '/Version.*.gnu.version_d/,/^$/'
Version definition section '.gnu.version_d' contains 8 entries:
  Addr: 0x000000000001b470  Offset: 0x01b470  Link: 4 (.dynstr)
  000000: Rev: 1  Flags: BASE   Index: 1  Cnt: 1  Name: libasound.so.2
  0x001c: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 2  Cnt: 1  Name: ALSA_0.9
  0x0038: Rev: 1  Flags: none  Index: 3  Cnt: 2  Name: ALSA_0.9.0rc4
  0x0054: Parent 1: ALSA_0.9
  [...]
```

---

The linker flag `-z,defs|--no-undefined` can be used to disallow unresolved symbols while linking:

```
$ g++ -Wl,-z,defs -shared -fPIC -o libmylib.so mylib.cpp 
/tmp/ccfJdVDG.o: In function `lib_func()':
mylib.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_sizeof'
mylib.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_sizeof'
mylib.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_open'
mylib.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_any'
mylib.cpp:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near'
mylib.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. You say this is by design and cite a paper on writing libraries (do you expect most users of ALSA to have naturally read it?), but I still think that this is poor design; apparently one of our teams has been plagued with this issue for years without anybody able to put their finger on it and I'm sure many users worldwide are too. I believe some mechanism must be developed, that would cause the combination of compile and link commands quoted in my question to fail with an error rather than silently link in the wrong version of a function.

Comment: (cont.) Whether this is possible and how this should be done (and would this be a modification to gcc, ALSA or both) is beyond my level of expertise, however.

Comment: There's the linker flag `-z,defs`. Maybe it should be on by default, but that is something that should be decided by distro toolchain maintainers and binutils upstream

Comment: This is garbage "design", I'm afraid. The right way to fix this situation is to remove the unversioned symbols from ALSA so that clients which are not properly built simply cannot resolve their references. Allowing code to call incorrect functions which do not match the header files cannot be called design.

Comment: @Kaz: Removing the old symbol would break compatibility with old binaries linked against the old version, so would require bumping ALSA's version. IMHO, the best way to avoid trouble like this would be to make `-z defs|--no-undefined` default, AFAICT, the main reason it isn't so, is to allow building plugins that call back to symbols defined by the main executable, and I don't think requiring passing a linker option to enable that use case would be unreasonable. But that is just my personal opinion.

Comment: @ninjalj Yes; basically it is not really reasonable to support old binary clients from the time when there was no symbol versioning, using the new library that has versioning. New lib, new soname (via new version or completely new name).  That way, distros that don't want the old don't even have to package it.

Comment: This too has been plaguing me, and adding the explicit link to asound fixed it for me. Thanks so much!